# How to suppress clutter parentheses in output?

Tags: output-formatting, boxes

Dozens of unnecessary parentheses are making my output hard to read.

For example, this:

```
expr = D[f[x], {x, 2}]^2;
```

returns this:

(* f"[x]^2  *)

But when I try to tidy up my output:

```
expr = D[f[x], {x, 2}]^2 /. Derivative[m_][f][x] -> Derivative[m][f]
```

it adds ()'s I didn't ask for:

(* (f")^2  *)

How do I make those not appear?

Comment: I guess this is a question for the main-page.

Comment: Looks like a feature of `Superscript`: `Superscript[x, y]^2`

Comment: Can you let me know how you want it to look? Did you try D[f[x], {x, 2}]^2 // TraditionalForm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## edit

This form might be better at catching just the desired parentheses

```
ToBoxes[expr] /. RowBox[{"(", a_SuperscriptBox, ")"}] :> RowBox[{a}]
```

## previous

Not terribly clean, but this works

```
DisplayForm[ToBoxes[expr] /. {"(" -> "", ")" -> ""}]
```

Comment: No guarantee that this will work out of the box with your real problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about ToBoxes. Is there a way to use Pattern and ToBoxes to make it only strip parentheses from around SuperscriptBox?